# swipe on listview to change add button to delete

Tags: android, button, android-listview

like Iphone Swipe functionality,how do we implement the same in Android,i have added the swipe code on getView method on adapter class

```
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "on long press...........",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        };
        listview.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

and the class is

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
    try {
           if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return true;
        // right to left swipe
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    // viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                    // viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                    // viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Item Click", "Item Click");
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "on long press...........",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "on show press...........",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

so please help me how i show the delete button in place of Add Button after swipe.

Answer (score 0):

u have to obtain/create delete button here and have to handle onClick() event of this...and for setting layout you have to pass x and y position actually where it should be display...

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        upX = event.getX();
        upY = event.getY();

        float deltaX = downX - upX;
        float deltaY = downY - upY;

        // horizontal swipe detection
        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
        // left or right
        if (deltaX < 0) {
            mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
            return false;
        }
        if (deltaX > 0) {
            mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
            deleteRow = (Button) v
                .findViewById(R.id.btnNoteListItemDelete);
            deleteRow.setVisibility(0);
            deleteRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("DELETING THIS ROW");
                deleteRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            });
            return true;
        }
        }

        mSwipeDetected = Action.Click;
        return false;
    }
    }
    return false;
    }
```